# How to delete an item from the update manager

Tags: update-manager

I need to delete an update from the update-manager. Until now I could not find the way to do it. Anybody may help?

Comment: Do you want to uninstall it or just not update it?

Comment: I can run the update-manager only if I uncheck one item. A message " Requires installation of untrusted packages" does not allow the update-manager to run. I uncheck the item and the other updates are processed. But the item remains in the update-manager ready to be installed next time. How do I get out this situation?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can not delete any updates from **Update Manager** unless it is not from third party sources.

Only you can do is to `untick` it i,e not to install while upgrading/updating your system. But be careful it would break your system and your system would become unstable. So do it only when you are fully determined what you're you going to do or you know what would be the result as an experienced user.

**Edit**

Be specific while asking a question that any one can understand. It seems that you've added 3rd party repositories which causing the trouble.

You first remove any third party repository before doing a update to your system. Follow these steps to remove all repositories except the original one which is provided by Ubuntu.

- Open Software Sources by executing:

  ```
  sudo software-properties-gtk
  ```
- Once opened go to <kbd>Other Software</kbd> tab and <kbd>Remove</kbd> all repositories except first 4.
- <kbd>Close</kbd> the window and update repository by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get -f update
  ```

Now again try to update your system. If you get again any error then try to update using terminal this time and paste the error message you get.

Comment: I can run the update-manager only if I uncheck one item. A message " Requires installation of untrusted packages" does not allow the update-manager to run. I uncheck the item and the other updates are processed. But the item remains in the update-manager ready to be installed next time. How do I get out this situation?

Comment: So this is your final problem.. Be specific while asking a question that any one can understand. It seems that you've added 3rd party repositories which causing the trouble. Give a look to my edit..

Answer (score 0):

Run the follow in the terminal to update an untrusted app.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And provide your password when asked.